# remove buckets which has doc_count zero in elastic search response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

While analyzing the elastic search response, I have seen the buckets are coming up even though the doc count is zero. Is there any configuration in elastic search to restrict the buckets which don't have any related documents?
below is my elastic search aggregation response.

```
{"depthAgg":{"buckets":[{"key":"*-10.0","to":10.0,"doc_count":0},{"key":"10.0-20.0","from":10.0,"to":20.0,"doc_count":0},{"key":"20.0-30.0","from":20.0,"to":30.0,"doc_count":0},{"key":"30.0-40.0","from":30.0,"to":40.0,"doc_count":0},{"key":"40.0-50.0","from":40.0,"to":50.0,"doc_count":1},{"key":"50.0-60.0","from":50.0,"to":60.0,"doc_count":1},{"key":"60.0-70.0","from":60.0,"to":70.0,"doc_count":0},{"key":"70.0-80.0","from":70.0,"to":80.0,"doc_count":0},{"key":"80.0-90.0","from":80.0,"to":90.0,"doc_count":0},{"key":"90.0-100.0","from":90.0,"to":100.0,"doc_count":0},{"key":"100.0-200.0","from":100.0,"to":200.0,"doc_count":0},{"key":"200.0-300.0","from":200.0,"to":300.0,"doc_count":0},{"key":"300.0-400.0","from":300.0,"to":400.0,"doc_count":0},{"key":"400.0-500.0","from":400.0,"to":500.0,"doc_count":0},{"key":"500.0-600.0","from":500.0,"to":600.0,"doc_count":0},{"key":"600.0-700.0","from":600.0,"to":700.0,"doc_count":0},{"key":"700.0-800.0","from":700.0,"to":800.0,"doc_count":0},{"key":"800.0-900.0","from":800.0,"to":900.0,"doc_count":0},{"key":"900.0-1000.0","from":900.0,"to":1000.0,"doc_count":0},{"key":"1000.0-*","from":1000.0,"doc_count":0}]}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you accept the answer if it answered your question

Answer (score 1):

For terms- and histogram-aggregations you can set `"min_doc_count": 1` to only return buckets that contain at least one document.

(see [Elasticsearch Reference: min_doc_count](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count_4))